# ReactJS - Component Still live after re-render of father

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some strange behavior about component lifecycle.

In my app, I have a Dashboard with several widgets inside. Every widget is a React Component.

GridWidgets.jsx is the father that manage every gadget.

When I switch to another dashboard, GridWidgets is re-rendered to load from the server the widgets for that dashboard. The render is correct, and the new widgets are rendered. Unfortunately, the old components from the previous dashboard, are still live (making stuff).

Searching on the web, I can't find any specific "unmount" procedure because, when a component re-render itself, it should drop its previous children.

The only "strange" things about my widget component, is that in their componentWillMount, I put this code:

```
setInterval(() => { this.internalRefresh(); this.loadData()}, this.props.widget_data.refresh * 1000);
```

That enables an auto-refresh every x seconds. LoadData is a function that calls a server to update widget data.

I'm afraid this interval makes the component not un-mountable.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the interval when you unmount the component. For this, you can make use of `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method in React

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => { 
         this.internalRefresh();
         this.loadData()
    }, this.props.widget_data.refresh * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think you meant to use `clearInterval(this.timer)`?

Comment: Thanks for correcting @deowk, I though of clearInterval and wrote clearTimeout mistakenly

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day!